# How do I ensure that my log4j is being called once in my unit testing

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sinon

I am using [sinon](/questions/tagged/sinon) with [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs).

How do I ensure that my `log4j` is being called once in my unit testing.

I am getting this error:

> TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property info as function.

main.js:

```
let log = require('log4js').getLogger("main");

...
personDao.updatePerson(param,
                (updatePerson) => updatePersonCallBack(updatePersonResult));
...

let updatePersonCallBack= exports.updatePersonCallBack= (result) => {
    log.info("SUCCESS", result)
}
```

main.spec.js:

```
it('updatePersonCallBack', (done) => {

        let getInfoSpy = sinon.spy(log, "info");

        let updatePersonResult= 1;

        main.updatePersonCallBack(updatePersonResult);
        should.equal(getInfoSpy.callCount, 1);

        done();
    });
```

Comment: The error seems like a reference issue, the program may be trying to use an undeclared function.

Comment: @rex nope. that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

you need to import/require log in spec/test file as well so that spy will identify log and info as its method. As log is not declared in the spec/test file, it will throw undefined error.

Comment: Your answer seemes quite unclear, please be more specific. [answer]